# Can't access MySQL through XAMPP and phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using XAMPP and I am trying to access phpMyAdmin through `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, but I'm getting this error message:

```
Error
SQL query: 

SHOW PLUGINS

MySQL said: 

#1 - Can't create/write to file '/var/folders/_y/gtpc137d1q9gkvsj0dsxjd040000gn/T/#sql9f2_8_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13)
```

I haven't tried to access it in a while so I don't know what has changed since the last time. Can anyone shed light on this for me? I've Googled and can't seem to understand what most people are talking about in related issues.

Also, my XAMPP won't connect to Apache anymore either (it just keeps giving me the loading image).

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
121201 22:59:27 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
Warning: World-writable config file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf' is ignored
121201 22:59:28 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for     /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
121201 22:59:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/folders/_y/gtpc137d1q9gkvsj0dsxjd040000gn/T/ibCVKOvf' (Errcode: 13)
121201 22:59:28  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
121201 22:59:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
121201 22:59:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
121201 22:59:29 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121201 22:59:29 [Note] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.44'  socket: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem already?

Comment: I never did. I've been editing through an internet connection connected to a database.

Comment: If you still wanna try: Tell us what the log under "XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/localhost.err" notes during startup.

Comment: Ok, I'd love to still figure it out. How do I get the log for .err? Sorry, I'm a little new to this!

Comment: in the directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/" is a file with the extension ".err". Open it after a restart of MySQL and copy+paste the messages logged there.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Regarding your issue that Apache won't startup - probably you have the native MacOSX web sharing enabled which means there is another Apache running already. Or it has to the with you previous port changes.

Comment: @MxmastaMills are you using a MAC that's on a domain.  I just had this same issue and I've never had it before on any other MAC.  This MAC is on a domain and I'm wondering if that is part of the reason that this happened.  I just installed the newest version of XAMPP yesterday and after I powered up this morning I experienced this.

Comment: I tried all of the above solutions & none worked. Then I found this (for Windows) and tried it on my Mac. It worked!!! https://docs.bitnami.com/general/faq/get-started/access-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Following line in the log is the reason:

> "Warning: World-writable config file
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf' is ignored"

As Rishi Kalia has pointed out already you have to set the correct permissions:

1. Open Terminal
2. Navigate to the XAMPP config folder

   **cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/**
3. Set permissions of `my.cnf` to `600`

   **sudo chmod 600 my.cnf**
4. Restart MySQL.

Comment: After running sudo chmod 600 my.cnf command all information from my.cnf is missing. Any suggestion how I can get default my.cnf file

Comment: IMO that's not possible as chmod alters the file on a meta-level only and no actual file contents are involved. But to restore just copy the orignal my.cnf from the XAMPP download package or reinstall.

Comment: The problem is if I reinstall XAMPP it may break my existing databases and I have many DB and huge size. Can I just restore my.cnf ?

Answer (score 7):

I had to reset the permissions in my xampp folder because I needed to be able to INSERT images into a folder in the htdocs, via php from website I am building.

However after I changed the permission I got : Errcode: 13

The process listed above works but I am adding some additional notes for people who have no clue how to use the terminal.

> #### 1. Open Terminal

- The Terminal is in  *Applications/Utilities/Terminal*

> #### 2. Navigate to the XAMPP config folder

- *pwd* shows the path listing to the current directory
- *cd* changes the current directory
- *ls -a*  lists all the files in that directory

Enter this code into the terminal: 
 **cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/**

> #### 3. Set permissions of my.cnf to 600

Enter this code into the terminal: 
**sudo chmod 600 my.cnf**

> #### 4. Restart MySQL

Voilà!

Answer (score 2):

you have to go to your xampp installation directory and change the permissions of `my.cnf` to 600

Comment: I changed the permissions from 3306 to 600 and it is still giving me the same error message unfortunately. Any idea why?

Comment: open terminal and navigate to the folder with `my.cnf` type: `sudo chmod 600 my.cnf` hit enter then input your password

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might have installed an application or a server which accesses the same port which is used by XAMPP. Try changing the port for the XAMPP server. Following link will help you.

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/

Comment: Ah, I tried to edit my httpd.conf file and now I can't connect at all. I had change the port from 80 to 44 and it didn't work so I just changed it back to 80 and now it won't connect at all. Any ideas why? It's the settings it was at initially...

Comment: Got it working again (I forgot to making it localhost:44 for the server). Problem is that I'm getting the same error message when trying to access mysql through localhost:44/phpmyadmin

Comment: did you try changing your windows security settings for the XAMPP home folder?

Comment: I have no experience on Mac. But check whether you XAMPP folder is having the full control for read, write and modify.

Answer (score 0):

**If you changed the write and read permissions in all the enclosed items inside the XAMPP main folder** ("/Applications/XAMPP"), be sure to make this folder Readable and Writable for *everyone*: "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql".

This can be done accessing to that folder from the Finder and then Get Info (Cmd + I), in the "Sharing & Permissions" click the lock icon, type your password and change "everyone - read only" to "everyone - read & write", and be sure to make that change for all the enclosed items as well (clicking the gear icon and then "Apply to enclosed items...").

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Pretty simple... once you take ownership of xamppfiles, you also need to update my.cnf file in the xamppfiles/etc/ directory.

Default MySQL password is `mysql`.

Once you authorized httpd service to run as User yourusername (OS X) Group yourgroup(id).

Open terminal and type in sudo whoami, this will tell you. In the my.cnf file, replace `mysql` with your user name.

Restart Apache.

Your username.pid file will be automatically updated.

Answer (score -1):

enter in folder etc
excute commande
sudo chmod 600 my.cnf

restart mysql server