# #1 - Can't create/write to file '/var/folders/

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I get the following error(see. figure) in my Xampp and can not access mySQL through XAMPP and phpMyAdmin. In this [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096617/cant-access-mysql-through-xampp-and-phpmyadmin/13669792?noredirect=1#comment29657396_13669792) and [link-2](https://www.blogging-it.com/cant-create-write-to-file-var-folders-fehlermeldung-bei-phpmyadmin-unter-xampp/betriebssysteme/mac-os-x.html) possible solution is given; but none of them woks in **Mac OS 10.9**

I assume the problem is with configuration file **my.cnf** which is located in the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf`.

Any suggestion will be appreciate. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Reinstall Xampp. Before reinstalling delete all the files, take away your htdoc and database folder to other place of your hdd. 
The **database location** in Mac OS-10.9 is

```
cd '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/'
```

**Htdoc location**

```
cd '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/'
```

When you complete reinstallation put all the folders to corresponding location and your database will be automatically update.

I looked some other solution but none of them seems work. I was scare if I remove the database to other location and import later will it work or not. And luckily it works, but as precaution careful when you remove big database.

Answer (score 15):

1. Completely stop XAMPP, this means stop apache, ftp and mysql.
2. Open the program called Terminal.
3. Type in sudo -i to become root (or do su root if the first doesn’t work for you).
4. You are most probably asked for a password which you have to enter while no characters are displayed.
5. Execute `chmod 600 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf` .
6. Exit your root shell with exit or just close Terminal.
7. Restart XAMPP (apache, ftp and mysql).

From: http://slopjong.de/2009/08/31/houston-i-cant-write-to-file/

Comment: it worked for me, i just wrote 'sudo chmod 600 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf' in terminal and restarted xampp. now phpmyadmin works fine